# Hibernate Mappings cannot be found, only when running from a JAR

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, jar, maven-assembly-plugin

I have project where in my **src/main/resources** I have two mapping files.

**Foo.hbm.xml**, **Bar.hbm.xml**

When running my main class from eclipse,  all works fine. When exporting to jar file using *maven assembly plugin*, I cannot create session factory due to missing mapping files. Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.MappingException: Resource: Foo.hbm.xml not found
```

**I am not using spring** altough I also tried with Spring and I have same problem Spring's session factory cannot find mapping when running from jar. My implementation is following. Code:

```
    Configuration hibernateConfig = new Configuration();
    hibernateConfig.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
    hibernateConfig.addResource("Foo.hbm.xml");
    hibernateConfig.addResource("Bar.hbm.xml");

    hibernateConfig.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", conf.dbUrl);
    hibernateConfig.setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", conf.dbUsername);
    hibernateConfig.setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", conf.dbPassword);
```

I have also tried to add mappings trough *hibernate.cfg.xml* but it did not work same result, works in eclipse but not when using runnable JAR. My maven assemly config  is following.

```
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
          <configuration>
            <descriptorRefs>
              <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
            </descriptorRefs>
            <archive>
              <manifest>
                <mainClass>com.app.EntryPoint</mainClass>
              </manifest>
            </archive>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

I create JAR with **mvn assembly:assembly** and when I open it mappings are there in root (/) of a JAR.

**EDIT**

Facepalm moment after looking at everything for 6 hours. **Foo.hbm.xml** was wrongly spelled so mapping was called MOTAccounts.hbm.xml and I used MotAccounts.hbm.xml.

What threw me off of this possibility was that everything worked in eclipse, but it didn't worked in a JAR. Like I said face palm moment.

Comment: Did you checked if the hbm.xml files are in the jar?

Comment: Yes they are in the root of the jar, this should be the classpath. I have tried also referencing them with classpath:Foo.hbm.xml but no cigar.

Comment: Which line of the 7 you posted does trigger the exception?

Comment: Thanks Ralph for trying to help I edited my post, seems it was one of those ... agh :)

Comment: This is what happens when you work with more people and your naming conventions differ.

Comment: The Windows file system is case insensitive, so it worked as long as the file is directly loaded. But the content in JARs is case sensitive.